# How to bind a property of a composing object

Tags: java, swing

I'm new in SwingBindings.

I have a list of beans named Project each Project has an reference to another bean named Config. Each Config has 2 attributes, how can I bind with swingbindings those two attributes of the bean Config to components form a jframe?

the list of projects is bound to a combobox. When I change the selected item from combobox(of project) I want to refresh the values from the object config associated to the current selected project in the form.

Comment: Don't know what you mean by "SwingBinding" - do you by any chance mean "beansbinding"? (with/or without Netbeans?)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

1. Create your own cell renderer that implements `ListCellRenderer`.
2. Assign that renderer to comboBox containing Projects. (`comboBox.setRenderer(...)`)
3. Now you can directly add your Project instance into comboBox and also get that back.
4. In ListCellRenderer in `getListCellRendererComponent(.....)` mehod cast `value` (Second argument) to Project and return appropriate value that you want to display in comboBox. (Might be project's name/title)
5. Add listener to comboBox. (May be `ItemListener`) and in its action method get selected object of comboBox, which will be your Project object.
6. From this project object you can easily get Config (as you said you have reference to Config object in Project object) object and set data in frame.

Comment: +1 good explanation for a custom renderer :-) My guess is, the OP really wants the binding ...

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I have figure out it's like this 
<pre>
org.jdesktop.beansbinding.Binding binding = org.jdesktop.beansbinding.Bindings.createAutoBinding(org.jdesktop.beansbinding.AutoBinding.UpdateStrategy.READ_WRITE, jcbProject, org.jdesktop.beansbinding.ELProperty.create("${selectedItem.config.updateDatabase}"), jCheckBox1, org.jdesktop.beansbinding.BeanProperty.create("selected"));
bindingGroup.addBinding(binding);
</pre>

Comment: the expression selectedItem.config.updateDatabase was not working and I found that the static variable form the bans which returns the name of the property must contain a string which should be exactly as the name of the variable.
Thank you.